# flash message setting through php ci

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to insert an entry to the database. First I check if the email id is already registered. If yes,a message is displayed stating that the email id is already taken, otherwise the data is inserted into database.

But the message is continuously displayed even after the page refresh. I want it to be disappeared with the page refresh.

```
    public function register()
    {   

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','required|is_unique[register.email]');
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){


             ////////////problem is here  ///////////////////////
            $this->load->view('view/login_register');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message_error','This id is already taken');

        }
        else
        {
           ///$username=$this->input->post('username');
            $email=$this->input->post('email');
            $data= array(

             ////'email'=>$this->input->post('email')
                'email'=>$email,   
          //'password'=>$this->input->post('password'),
                );

            $last_id=$this->model->registeration($data);

            if ($last_id>0) {

                $this->send_email($email);


                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'To complete registration, click the link in email we just send you at khadija@precisetech.com.pk');
                redirect('controller/register');
            }


        } 
    if(error_flag == 1){
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  }
```

[for your help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jadYC.png)

Comment: Load view after setting flash. Try that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have another way to do it. It is as follows:

- In Controller:

  ```
  if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){


      $data['msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" type="button">×</button>This id is already taken.</div>';
      $this->load->view('view/login_register', $data);


  }
  ```
- And in view do like this:

  ```
  <?php if(isset($msg)){echo $msg ;} ?>
  ```